# Azure Data Warehouse - fixing bigint value in a Float datatype column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a column that is of `float` datatype. There is a bad data with a `bigint` value. The value is `-4.66606E+22`.

I tried the following logic but it is not working.

1. Using a case statement to check for the column is falling between the float min and max range, if not then change it to 0.
2. ISNULL(TRY_CAST(Column1 AS FLOAT), 0) but this does not work as ours is Azure Data warehouse.

```
Select 
    case 
        when Column1 > '1.79E+32' then 0
        when Column1 < '-1.79E+32' then 0
        Else Column1 
    End as Column1 
From Table1
```

I also tried

```
Select 
    case 
        when Column1 between '1.79E+32' and '-1.79E+32' then Column1 
        Else 0
    End as Column1 
From Table1
```

Expected is to replace the `-4.66606E+22` with `0`.

Comment: I think the range for big int is -9,22E+18 to 9.22E+18. It might be E+17 I am not good with the conversion

Comment: You know that `-4.66606E+22` is **between** `-1.79E+32` and `1.79E+32`, right? Your code will not replace it wit zero, because it is in your "valid range" of values.

Comment: Aside: There is no benefit to comparing a `float` to a string, e.g. `Column1 > '1.79E+32'`. Rather than having SQL Server perform an implicit cast from string to float just use `Column1 > 1.79E+32`.

Answer (score 0):

The range of `bigint` is `-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808)` to `2^63-1 .(9,223,372,036,854,775,807)`.
And the range of `float` is `- 1.79E+308` to `-2.23E-308`, `0` and `2.23E-308` to `1.79E+308`

we can see here：
[image]

Reference:

1. [float and real](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
2. [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

The `bigint` data `-4.66606E+22` is in range of float. This why your code doesn't work. And as HABO said there is no benefit to comparing a float to a string, e.g.

You want replace the -4.66606E+22 with 0, maybe you can try:

```
Select
    case  Column1
        when  -4.66606E+22 then 0 
    End 
From Table1
```

Hope this can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the [`BigInt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) range: -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807). That's about ±9E+18, so -4.66606E+22 isn't a likely `BigInt` value.

Moving on to comparing values of different data types:

```
declare @Foo as BigInt = 8765432109876543210;
declare @FloatFoo as Float(24) = @Foo, @DoubleFoo as Float(53) = @Foo;

-- According to the rules for data type preedence a BigInt value will be converted to a Float
--   when the two data types are compared. Hence all of the values are "equal".
select @Foo as Foo,
  @FloatFoo as FloatFoo, case when @Foo = @FloatFoo then 1 else 0 end as FloatMatch,
  @DoubleFoo as DoubleFoo, case when @Foo = @DoubleFoo then 1 else 0 end as DoubleMatch;

-- Since a Float(53) has a precision of 15 digits that means some precision will be lost.
set @Foo += 1; -- Bump the BigInt value, but leave the Floats unchanged.
-- And ... the values are all still "equal"!
select @Foo as Foo,
  @FloatFoo as FloatFoo, case when @Foo = @FloatFoo then 1 else 0 end as FloatMatch,
  @DoubleFoo as DoubleFoo, case when @Foo = @DoubleFoo then 1 else 0 end as DoubleMatch;

-- Once more, with feeling.
set @Foo += 1000; -- A bigger bump makes the Float(53) value different, but not the Float(24).
select @Foo as Foo,
  @FloatFoo as FloatFoo, case when @Foo = @FloatFoo then 1 else 0 end as FloatMatch,
  @DoubleFoo as DoubleFoo, case when @Foo = @DoubleFoo then 1 else 0 end as DoubleMatch;
```

Ref's: [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`Float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Executive Summary: "There is a bad data with a `bigint` value. The value is `-4.66606E+22`." That's *really* bad data. And comparing `BigInt` and `Float` values is an imprecise activity likely to result in disappointment.